# I need to make the gallons of water used 0.8 instead of 99999999.2? This is when c is inputted as the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
code = input("Enter the customer's code:")
b_meter = int(input("Enter the customer's beginning meter reading:"))
e_meter = int(input("The customer's ending meter reading:"))
if e_meter > b_meter:
   used_gallons = e_meter - b_meter
else:
   used_gallons = b_meter - e_meter
if code == 'r':
   cost_gallons = float((used_gallons * 0.0005) + 5)
if code == 'c':
   if used_gallons < 4000000:
       cost_gallons = 1000
   else:
       cost_gallons = (used_gallons) * 0.00025

print('Customer code:', code)
print('Beginner meter reading:', b_meter)
print('Ending meter reading:', e_meter)
print('Gallons of water used:', used_gallons / 10)
print('Amount billed:$',"{:0.2}".format(cost_gallons))
```

#output
Enter the customer's code:c
Enter the customer's beginning meter reading:999999997
The customer's ending meter reading:000000005
Customer code: c
Beginner meter reading: 999999997
Ending meter reading: 5
Gallons of water used: 99999999.2
Amount billed:$ 2.5e+05

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide more details. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following change

```
if e_meter > b_meter:
    used_gallons = e_meter - b_meter
else:
    used_gallons = 1000000000 - (b_meter - e_meter)
```

You need to change `(b_meter - e_meter)` in else clause to `1000000000 - (b_meter - e_meter)`

Comment: It returned with a Valueerror: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier line 29, in <module>
    print('Amount billed:$', "{:0.2}".format(cost_gallons))